# SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end execution ERROR

Tags: sonarqube

[image: SonarQube MSBuild ERROR]

Please find the error details in screen shot. Please suggest your ideas to resolve this error.

Version Used:
SonarQube-5.6.6

Comment: Remove the sonar-project.properties file and start your build pipeline again. If you are using Visual Studio Team Services be sure to use the SonarQube tasks from the Marketplace.

Comment: @Jeroen: Hi thanks for the response,  
Removed the sonar-project.properties file from project root path and tried again. Now getting error like "No Analysable projects were found. SonarAnalysis will not be performed" and "Generation of the sonar-properties file failed". Please help
Now I'm using sonarqube-5.6.6

Comment: It seems you don't have analyzable project. What kind of projects do you have in the solution? What is the version of MSBuild with which you build the solution, and what are the versions of the analyzers in your SonarQube?

Comment: @Janos, Hi, Thanks. Version details: .Net core app, sonarqube-5.6.6(LTS), sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.0.629, MSBuild\14.0

Comment: Are you using TFS build or are you executing the analysis by hand?

Comment: @Ganesh what kind of projects do you have in the solution, and how many of them?

Comment: Actually, my local sonarQube server is working fine by displaying all bugs, VULNERABILITIES and other details but I'm trying to get code coverage results into my local SonarQube. So I tried using this MSBuild, we have 7Dev proj & 4Test proj. in my solution. And I'm totally new to this sonarQube, plz excuse if anything is not correct. thanks

Comment: @Jeroen : I'm doing analysis by hand. I'm following the steps mentioned in the below url
https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770#CodeCoverageResultsImport(C#,VB.NET)-VisualStudioCodeCoverage

Comment: Did you have a look at the contents of VisualStudio.coverage and VisualStudio.coveragexml?